# Backbone model .toJSON() doesn't render all attributes to JSON

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I need to render a model's attributes to JSON so I can pass them into a template.
Here is what a render() function for a view looks like:

```
render: function() {
  console.log(this.model);
  console.log(this.model.toJSON());
  $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
  return this;
},
```

Here is the attributes output after doing console.log(this.model):

```
created_at: "2012-04-19"
id: "29"
name: "item"
resource_uri: "/api/v1/item/29/"
updated_at: "2012-04-21"
user: "/api/v1/user/9/"
```

Here is the model's JSON output after doing console.log(this.model.toJSON()):

```
id: "29"
__proto__: Object
```

What happened?

Edit:
Here is the instantiation:

```
  var goal = new Goal({id: id});
  goal.fetch();
  var goalFullView = new GoalFullView({
    model: goal,
  });
```

Here are the contents of the new view:

```
  console.log(this.model.attributes);
  console.log(this.model.toJSON());
```

Here is what the console says:

```
Object
created_at: "2012-04-23"
id: "32"
name: "test"
resource_uri: "/api/v1/goal/32/"
updated_at: "2012-04-23"
user: "/api/v1/user/9/"
__proto__: Object

Object
id: "32"
name: "test"
__proto__: Object
```

If the toJSON is supposed to make a clone of the attributes, why doesn't it copy the correct name or why doesn't it copy the created_at, updated_at fields?

Edit 2:
Here is the model:

```
  var Goal = Backbone.Model.extend({

    // Default attributes for Goal
    defaults: {
      name: "empty goal",
    },

    // Check that the user entered a goal
    validate: function(attrs) {
      if (!attrs.name) {
        return "name is blank";
      }
    },

    // Do HTTP requests on this endpoint
    url: function() {
      if (this.isNew()) {
        return API_URL + "goal/" + this.get("id") + FORMAT_JSON;
      }
      return API_URL + "goal/" + FORMAT_JSON;
      //API_URL + "goal" + FORMAT_JSON, 
    },
  });
```

Edit 3:
I figured out that I need to use the success callback from fetch to render a view that uses the model:

goal.fetch({success: function(model) {
    var goalFullView = new GoalFullView({
      model: goal,
    });
  }});

Comment: can you show the model and its instantiation as well?

Comment: You have something else in your code that makes the other attributes invisible for toJSON(), perhaps look at your Model or paste, how you are initializing it ... see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/drinchev/JLfJB/1/)

Comment: I edited the original post with the Model class. I cannot seem to figure out why the toJSON does not work. Even though, this.model.attributes prints out the correct list of attributes, when I try to do this.model.get("id") or any of the other attributes, they come up as empty. Clearly, it is present when I call attributes on the model instance, though.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The `toJSON()` method just returns a shallow clone of the model's `attributes` property.

From the [annotated Backbone.js source](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-36):

```
toJSON: function(options) {
  return _.clone(this.attributes);
}
```

Without seeing more of your code, it looks like you directly set properties on the model object, rather than using the `set` function to set model attributes.

I.e. don't do this:

```
model.name = "item";
```

do this:

```
model.set("name", "item");
```

EDIT:

For your specific issue, it's possible that you called toJSON before the model had finished loading from the server.

E.g. This won't always work as expected:

```
var model = new Goal({id: 123});
model.fetch();
console.log(model.toJSON());
```

But this will:

```
var model = new Goal({id: 123});
model.fetch({
  success: function() {
    console.log(model.toJSON());
  }
});
```

Comment: Backbone docs also state > The attributes property is the internal hash containing the model's state. Please use set to update the attributes instead of modifying them directly. If you'd like to retrieve and munge a copy of the model's attributes, use toJSON instead.

Comment: Alternative set syntax: `model.set({name: "item"})` - this form lets you set many properties at once, too.