# Simple Parse.com Localstorage solution

Tags: local-storage, parse-platform

Does anyone have a good solution for storing `Parse.com objects` into localStorage for `Javascript` projects?

The problem I have come across is that when converting the `object to JSON`, we lose the id on the object. This is because the id in `Parse.com objects` isn't stored in the attributes.
Give me some hint.
Thanks in Advance.

Update 
My little example

```
var Something = Parse.Object.extend("Something");
var something = new Something();
something.set("attribute1", "attribute1");
something.save(null, {
        success: function(obj) {
            something.fetch({
                success: function(obj) {
                    console.log("object:"); console.log(obj); 
                    console.log("json:");     console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
                },
            })
        },
    })
```

Which give this output:

```
object: appmob.js:1563
d.hasOwnProperty.f
_changing: false
_escapedAttributes: Object
_existed: true
_hasData: true
_hashedJSON: Object
_opSetQueue: Array[1]
_pending: Object
_previousAttributes: Object
_saving: false
_serverData: Object
_silent: Object
attributes: Object
changed: Object
cid: "c0"
createdAt: Mon Sep 03 2012 15:43:50 GMT+1000 (EST)
id: "e419YJmhR5"
updatedAt: Mon Sep 03 2012 15:43:50 GMT+1000 (EST)
__proto__: c
```

** which has the id.

```
json: 
{"attribute1":"attribute1","attribute2":"attribute2"}
```

** which doesn't have the id.

This is related to this stackoverflow question
[Backbone model .toJSON() doesn't render all attributes to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10262498/backbone-model-tojson-doesnt-render-all-attributes-to-json)

So I was wondering what would be the simplest way to store the JSON string into localstorage.

Comment: According to the REST docs, the IDs are indeed returned in objects, https://parse.com/docs/rest#objects-retrieving, see the objectId field. Are you not seeing that?

Comment: Hi Ray,I am using the Javascript API. https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#objects-retrieving. When you fetch an object the id is an attribute of the object. Whilst the attributes for the object are store in an array called attributes. When you call getJSON() on the object it returns the values of the attributes array as an object minus the id.

Comment: So to be clear, you can't do ob.id as they have documented? Do you have this online where we can see?

Comment: @RaymondCamden Hi Ray. I ve updated the question with a code example.

Comment: Wow - I hope your edit also changed some of the text, if not, I really misread your question and I apologize. I thought you were saying that the result from the Parse API for an object didn't include the object. But instead, you are saying that it does, but when you convert the result to JSON, you don't get the ID in the string. That's totally different. Let me try to recreate this.

Comment: Ok, so far I can't reproduce this, but my code is somewhat simpler then yours. Check the Gist: https://gist.github.com/3609380. To test this, I ran Chrome with the flag to allow remote XHR requests. Also, this was based on a PhoneGap example so you can see the ondeviceready stuff. Point is - I get the objects from Parse and in the stringify I clearly see the id. I noticed your doing something a bit fancy compared to me though.

Comment: Fascinating. So previously I had used their REST API. That's why it worked. I'm now testing with their JS API and I see what you see. Interestingly - their Object class has a toJSON method. Guess what though - it also doesn't store the ID - which makes no sense as their docs say it is what you would use if you wanted to store the result back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so from what I can tell (see comments above), the native JS API for Parse assumes you only want to serialize the attributes (ie core data) of objects and NOT the actual metadata, including ID, created, etc. Since they really want you to store stuff ONLY on their system, this makes sense. However, you can write your own code to handle this yourself. For example, this method below grabs two metadata keys (id and createdAt, there IS more, but I was just testing) and creates a key called 'data' for the core attributes.

```
function serializeParseObject(pob) {
  var ob = {};
  ob.id = pob.id;
  ob.createdAt = pob.createdAt;
  ob.data = pob.attributes;
  return JSON.stringify(ob);
}
```

I tested this a sample result object and it worked ok. Again though you probably want to add the other metadata keys for completeness. (Or maybe you only care about id.)

Comment: Thanks @raymond. I guess they do want data to be stored on their system. I am using localstorage to cut down on the calls to the parse cloud.

Answer (score 3):

You might be interested to know an updated Parse did to their JS SDK:

v1.1.10 — November 13, 2012

Extended JSON serialization for Parse.Object: Calling JSON.stringify() on a Parse.Object will now include the default attributes 'objectId', 'createAt', and 'updatedAt' in the output.

Comment: Ah.. Cool. Thanks for updating this answer.